# How to include forms over bg image and beside navbar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

First problem; I have very little working knowledge of Bootstrap/CSS and have copied code from various places and adapted it myself to make my solution work.
Second problem; I know I need containers/rows/columns, but I'm unsure of how to nest them appropriately around my navbar (permanently affixed to the left) and on top of the background image.
This is for a mobile web application and I would like to create forms that will sit on top of the background image.

I have spent nearly 2 whole days researching and inserting containers, rows, columns, around my existing code but all it achieves is moving the layout, moving navbar to the centre and text appears above or below the image but not on top of the image. The background image is set in css in the head, code is below.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  background: url("Red_polygon.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.navbar-custom {
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 1)
}

.thumbnail {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px 0px 2px 2px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="thumbnail" border="0">
    <img src="ASD_header_logo.png" alt="Active Software Development" width=277 height=76 />
  </div>
</nav>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="thumbnail" border="0">
      <img src="ASD_header_logo.png" alt="Active Software Development" width=277 height=76 />
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="bg">
    <div class="wrapper">
    </div>
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <p>
          <center>
            <h4>Management Information System</h4>
          </center>
        </p>
        <li>
          <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Project nav</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Activities</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Tasks</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Staff</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Help</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

I am expecting there is something I have done incorrectly to structure the navbar and background image and just wondering if someone can help me understand what I have done wrong, and how to correct it. Apologies for the massive amount of code but I'm unsure what's relevant and what isn't after the amount of things I've tried. Thank you in advance and kindest regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have inserted a very basic structure to incorporate what you have mentioned above. However, not sure if what you are intending with the code you have mentioned above. So let's talk further if you need more help.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  background: url("https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/130000/velka/abstract-magical-background.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.navbar-custom {
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 1)
}

.thumbnail {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px 0px 2px 2px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body class="">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="thumbnail" border="0">
      <img src="ASD_header_logo.png" alt="Active Software Development" width=277 height=76 />
    </div>
  </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
         <nav id="sidebar">
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
          <p>
            <center>
              <h4>Management Information System</h4>
            </center>
          </p>
          <li>
            <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Project nav</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Activities</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Tasks</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Staff</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Help</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
        <div class="bg">
        <form class="text-white">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Hi Charu, thank you for your response. It has worked, but I do have some white space which is probably due to the amount of css on the sidebar. However I can now work around this and will learn from my mistakes. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Great! All the best